# azure devops: copy and publish build artifacts - rename artifact by buildnumber

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to know how to change the **Artifact Name** with a build variable.
My preferred result would be

```
MyApplication_[My Build Number]
```

How can i achieve this. In the picture below are my current settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As artifact name, enter

```
 ArtifactName_$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on this solution, this is setting the artifact's name, not the file(s) included in the artifact. If you set

```
         - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
            targetPath: 'targetPath'
            artifact: ' ArtifactName_$(Build.BuildNumber)'
            publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

you'll see an artifact published named `ArtifactName_$(Build number....)` but the contents of the folder will be unchanged in name.